# Scanner's function .nextLine() wont accept input inside a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, while-loop

I need to have the user input a size of the array in the variable `n` and then create a single dimension array of Strings and have it filled with sentences. I also need to make sure that each sentence ends with a full stop (a `.` ). so here's what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
class encryption{
        void main(){
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the number of sentences to be encrypted");
                int n=sc.nextInt();
                String[] a=new String[n];
                System.out.println("Enter the sentences");

                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    a[i]=sc.nextLine();
                    while(a[i].charAt(a[i].length()-1)!='.'){
                        a[i]=sc.nextLine();                                                
                    }
                    if(i%2==0){
                        a[i]=rev(a[i]);
                    }
                    else{
                        a[i]=frwd(a[i]);
                    }

                }
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                }
            }
```

After the inputs, I will work on the Strings using the functions `rev(...)` and `frwd(...)`, and then print the changed strings.

It compiles fine, however upon execution, the first line in the first `for` loop `a[i]=sc.nextLine();` doesn't seem work. It gives me a straight  `indexOutOfBounds` error meaning it goes straight onto the `while` loop.

How can I make it accept input there?

Comment: You can add an extra `sc.nextLine()` to consume the last newline character. You might find reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo) helpful.

Comment: @HardikModha that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you take the number of sentences in the variable n,
write this line of code:

```
int n=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```